# Recover databases after upgrade to MySQL 5.7 on Mac OS?

Tags: mysql, database, macos, mysql-5.7

I've updated the MySQL version from 5.5 to 5.7. After the update, I got my password reset (which is done by default) and I changed it back to the one I used before - all good!

The problem is that when I log into phpmyadmin and I don't see the databases that I had before the upgrade.

I'm pretty sure they are not lost, but since I'm not an expert with MySQL and OSX I need a piece of advice how to recover them.

Comment: Are you sure you updated correctly? Maybe you installed a new database (and thus got a new pw) instead of upgrading (which should not reset your password). Do you get any error messages (missing plugins, ...) when you start the MySQL server? Can you login by other means (workbench/command line client/...) and see the missing data? Try searching your disks for files like `ibdata*`, `*.ibd` or `*.myd`. You might have two data directories (one for 5.5/old data, one for your new empty 5.7 installation). If nothing works: Your data will of course be in the backup you took before you did an update.

Comment: @Solarflare actually I did not backup the DBs before upgrading :( Lucky for me searching for `ibdata` got me to the directory of the previous version of MySQL and I was able to recover from the physical files. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem.  My question, how did you recover from the physical files?  I copied them to the new data folder but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL installer on macOS installs MySQL into `/usr/local/mysql-version`. It then makes a symlink to `/usr/local/mysql`. The old data is still there, in

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.../data
```